# save data from datagridview to xml

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have 1 form, where *button1* draw table at *datagridview*.
After filling the cells, i need to save data from *datagridview* to xml by *button2*.

```
//save
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        
            try
            {                      
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds = (DataSet)(dataGridView1.DataSource);
                ds.WriteXml(@"c:\1.xml");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
            }            
        }

//draw a datagridview    
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    int x, y;
                    x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                    y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                    double[,] grid;
                    grid = new double[x, y];
                    int k = 0;
                    k = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
                    if (k != 0)
                        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                            dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
                    AddColumns(y, dataGridView1);
                    AddRows(x, dataGridView1);
                    dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 22;                                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex.Message);
                }

            }
```

but i received error:

> object reference not set to an instantce of an object.

**So, how can i save datagridview to xml?**

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set the data source to the datagridview?

Comment: Apparently there is no DataSource bound to the datagridview control. How do you work with this datagrid? Having more code would be nice..

Answer (score 2):

I expect your dgv does not have a valid datasource. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) for info on how to bind a data source How did you populate the dgv with data?

You could try serialization, but DataGridView is not serializable, you will need to iterate through your dgv (datagridview) and add each item to a collection. It would probably be best to create a structure that will repesent the data of your dgv and declare that as `[Serializable()]`. Each field could be stored as a string, so just iterate through the dgv, call `ToString()` on each item and add it to an instance of your structure. Iterate through the rows of your dgv something like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      //add each row and item to your structure
 }
```

Alternatively, if you do have a datasource then this could be serialized more directly.

So now you have a collection that IS serializeable and it's filled with all of your data. Now you need to serialize that structure and then write it to file, like:

```
XmlSerializer izer = new XmlSerializer(YourStructure.GetType());
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"c:\1.xml");
izer.Serialize(WriteFileStream, YourStructure);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

I hope this helps, info on serialization can be found [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm). Remember, you can create a handler for your button OnClick event by doubleclicking on the button in the design view.